# tinymce: database content not loaded into textarea

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce

I have a textarea with an id of 'text'. tinyMce control is successfully added to the div containing the textarea. Using the following javascript after the textarea has written been out in PHP:
"tinyMCE.get('text').setContent('blah');return false;"

I still get a blank textarea.

On first load of the page, I get the editor menu bar over the textarea as expected. There's a javascript onclick action on a button that calls (it does so) a PHP script via AJAX and that's where the textarea content should be loaded. The inner HTML produced inside a DIV when the button is clicked is:

```
{"innerHTML":"<textarea class=\"formElements\" name=\"text\" id=\"text\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" >Blah and more blah<\/textarea>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n<!--\ntinyMCE.get('text').setContent('blah');return false;\n\/\/-->\n<\/script>\n"}
```

The attempt to use tinyMCE.get() is a test because the 'Blah and more blah' (pulled from a database) is not being set in the textarea HTML. In the DOM, after clicking the button, tinymce's domLoaded is true.

There are no errors or warning in Firebug.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if text is your textarea's id than why you are not using # before your id

```
{"innerHTML":"<textarea class=\"formElements\" name=\"text\" id=\"text\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" >Blah and more blah<\/textarea>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n<!--\ntinyMCE.get('#text').setContent('blah');return false;\n\/\/-->\n<\/script>\n"}
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek,

I've added the # so the HTML produced is now:
{"innerHTML":"<textarea class=\"formElements\" name=\"text\" id=\"text\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" >Blah and more blah<\/textarea>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n<!--\ntinyMCE.get('#text').setContent('blah');return false;\n\/\/-->\n<\/script>\n"}

but still nothing happening.

Comment: have you checked console is there any warning or error?

Comment: As stated above, Firebug gives no errors or warnings whether I use '#text' or not.